# How to add elements in one list to another?

Tags: python, list, addition

This may not a be question well received by the SO community. I am a 12 year old beginner Python coder and I am working on this project to gather Corona stats across multiple websites and GitHub posts. Then I would turn that into a graph. Some lists that have been created will have been generated by one country but in different provinces. So what I need to do is add each element in a list to another element in a list so that I can have only one list of the country.
I have appended two or more list to one list called full and formatted it a bit and it looks a bit like this:

```
['China', '  8', '  8', '  8', '  8', '  8', '  8', '  8', 
 'China', '  2', '  2', '  2', '  2', '  2', '  2', '  2', 
 'China', '  6', '  6', '  6', '  6', '  6', '  6', '  6', 
 'China', '  22', '  22', '  22', '  22', '  22', '  22', '  22']
```

## My Goal

---

So I need to add 8 to two for example and put that into a list:

[image: An illustrative picture]

Now that's simple:

```
list1 = full[1]+full[3]
```

But what if I needed to add multiple elements in a list to each other and the amount of lists in full(my list) where different every time(this would happened because China could have 8 provinces so I created 8 list while India has 50 provinces so I create 50 list).

## Result

---

So here is what I would like to get but can't figure out.

```
['China', '8','7','2', 'China','2','34','18']
['India', '8','7','2', 'India','2','34','8','India','2','231','44']

China = ['10','41','20']
India = ['12','271','55']
```

Here is my code:

```
file = open('similar.txt','r')
L = []
full = []
final = []
countryName = ''
numfinal = 0
for row in file:
    count = 1
    row = row[:-2]
    row = row[1:]
    L.append(row)
    for i in L:
        L = i.split(',')
    L = [i.replace('\n','')for i in L]
    L = [i.replace('\'','') for i in L]  

    if L[0] == countryName:
        for i in L:
            full.append(i)
        print(full)
    else:
        countryName = L[0]
        full.clear()
```

(There is more but those files don't matter for my problem. Also it reads from a file that includes all the countries with more than more province. It is a bit too much to paste so I have a curl below)
curl-    O'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BuddyBob/Py_Programs/master/Hackathon/Deaths/similar.txt'
Or just use the link. Any help would be much appreciated

Here is a couple of lines from similar.txt:

```
['Australia', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0']
['Australia', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4']
['Australia', ' 83', ' 92', ' 105', ' 112', ' 116', ' 123', ' 123']
['Canada', ' 7', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8']
['Canada', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3']
['Canada', ' 2807', ' 2812', ' 2813', ' 2816', ' 2819', ' 2821', ' 2822']
['Canada', ' 5667', ' 5670', ' 5670', ' 5673', ' 5674', ' 5678', ' 5681']
['China', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1']
['China', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8']
```

Comment: You need to either join two lists into a new list with a `+`, or `one_list.extend(another_list)` to put values from `another_list` into `one_list`. Check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). I would recommend against mixing different kinds of items in a flat list; consider a structure like `[('China', 1, 2), ('India', 3, 4)]` which is much easier to operate.

Comment: Is each list going to be their own country? And are the number of integers per country the same?

Comment: Can you please post a few lines from the `similar.txt` file?

Comment: @jab Yes I will take every province of china for example and add each element to make 1 list with the same length as list one or two. Each country will have the same amount of integers(7)

Comment: @9000 sure I'll post a couple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an illustration of one way to group and sum the data. There are definitely shorter and fancier ways to do this sort of thing, but this example breaks the steps down.

```
import json

# Your lists.
raw_lists = [
    ['Australia', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0'],
    ['Australia', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4'],
    ['Australia', ' 83', ' 92', ' 105', ' 112', ' 116', ' 123', ' 123'],
    ['Canada', ' 7', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8'],
    ['Canada', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3'],
    ['Canada', ' 2807', ' 2812', ' 2813', ' 2816', ' 2819', ' 2821', ' 2822'],
    ['Canada', ' 5667', ' 5670', ' 5670', ' 5673', ' 5674', ' 5678', ' 5681'],
    ['China', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1'],
    ['China', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8', ' 8'],
    ['China', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2'],
    ['China', ' 6', ' 6', ' 6', ' 6', ' 6', ' 6', ' 6'],
    ['China', ' 22', ' 22', ' 22', ' 22', ' 22', ' 22', ' 22'],
    ['China', ' 4512', ' 4512', ' 4512', ' 4512', ' 4512', ' 4512', ' 4512'],
    ['China', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1'],
    ['China', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1'],
    ['China', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2'],
    ['China', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0'],
    ['China', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3'],
    ['China', ' 7', ' 7', ' 7', ' 7', ' 7', ' 7', ' 7'],
    ['China', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3'],
    ['China', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0'],
    ['China', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2'],
    ['Denmark', ' 613', ' 613', ' 614', ' 615', ' 615', ' 615', ' 615'],
    ['France', ' 38', ' 38', ' 39', ' 39', ' 39', ' 39', ' 39'],
    ['France', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4', ' 4'],
    ['France', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3'],
    ['France', ' 30096', ' 30109', ' 30108', ' 30123', ' 30150', ' 30150', ' 30150'],
    ['Netherlands', ' 15', ' 15', ' 15', ' 15', ' 15', ' 15', ' 16'],
    ['United Kingdom', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1'],
]

# Group the lists based on country. This will give us a dict-of-lists-of-lists.
# Like this: grouped_lists{COUNTRY} = [ [...], [...], etc ]
grouped_lists = {}
for xs in raw_lists:
    # Grab country name and the rest of the values.
    c = xs[0]
    vals = xs[1:]
    assert len(vals) == 7
    # Convert the values to integers using a list comprehension.
    nums = [int(v.strip()) for v in vals]
    # Add the list of numbers to the country's list-of-lists.
    grouped_lists.setdefault(c, []).append(nums)

# Sum up the separate lists for each country.
country_totals = {}
for c, xss in grouped_lists.items():
    # Initialize the key for the country.
    country_totals[c] = []
    # Since xss is a list-of-lists for the current country, we can use zip() to
    # weave together the values based on their positions (or indexes). For
    # example, on the first iteration tup will be a tuple holding the first
    # elements from the separate lists. On second iteration, second elements. Etc.
    for tup in zip(*xss):
        country_totals[c].append(sum(tup))

# Take a look.
print(json.dumps(country_totals))
```

Comment: Hey man sorry for the late response I have been tryna get your code to work properly with my code. And in the end it worked so I just wanna say thanks I accepted the answer and gave it an upvote. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to get the grouped numbers, and for your key just determine if the string is a number (I used `str.isdigit`).

Then convert them to numbers,

Finally perform an element-wise sum to the result (which can be done using `map` and `operator.add`).

This can all be done in one line.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import add

data = ['China', '8','7','2', 'China','2','34','18']

china = list(map(add, *(tuple(map(int, g)) for k, g in groupby(data, str.isdigit) if k)))
```

Result:

```
[10, 41, 20]
```

Comment: Just running your answer in a separate file I get an error:   `    full = list(map(add, *(tuple(map(int, g)) for k, g in groupby(L, str.isdigit) if k)))
TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments.` What might be happening?(Your answer seems solid though)

Comment: Are you sure you're giving it the data the same way as I am?

Comment: Ye I created a new file and copied your code. I am using python 3.8, you?

Comment: What I'm saying is does `L` in your comment look like `data` in my answer.

Comment: No I don't think you understand. I literally copied you code. Nothing different just the same thing the same variables and everything is just the same. A simple copy and paste. I put it in a seperate file just to test it out and it did not work.